# Node.js - Get all tables from .mdb

Tags: node.js, adodb

Is it possible to list all table names from a `.mdb` database in node.js?

I tried [node-adodb](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-adodb) module, but I can't find the right SQL command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newest version of `node-adodb` module has implemented OpenSchema. This version is not published on NPM yet. You can install it from [github](https://github.com/nuintun/node-adodb).

This is the code that lists all tables from a database:

```
const ADODB = require('node-adodb');
const connection = ADODB.open('Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=DB1.mdb;');

connection
    .schema(20)
    .then((schema) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(schema, null, 2));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```